# How to compare a location with Home folder in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, shell

I have tried to run a script in a specific location but I could not and I realize that is related to the following code which I assumed should return True but it actually returns False if you are in the home folder in windows 10.

```
$loc=Get-Location 
$loc -eq $HOME  =>> Should return True but it is not.
```

So any comment or answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Get-Location` returns a location *object*, whereas `$home` is just a string. Either convert `$loc` to a string, or compare `$home` to its `Path` property:

```bsh
$loc.Path -eq $home
# or 
"$loc" -eq $home
```

Since PowerShell's `-eq` operator behaves according to the type of the left-hand side operand, you could also flip the two operands and it'll work as well:

```bsh
$home -eq $loc
```

Answer (score 3):

[Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62410379/45375) shows that `Get-Location` returns a [`System.Management.Automation.PathInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PathInfo) instance rather than a string and how to account for that.

There is a **small caveat**, however:

While probably rare in practice, a test based on the returned object's `.Path` property and the equivalent implicit stringification of the whole object via `"..."` *may* still fail, namely if the current location is based on a *custom PowerShell drive*:

`.Path` then reports the *PowerShell-specific* path, whereas `$HOME` is always expressed as a *file-system-native* path, so even if the two paths ultimately refer to the same file-system location, `-eq` will not detect that.

To account for that, use the **`.ProviderPath` property** instead, which - just like `$HOME` - expresses the directory as a *file-system-native path*:

```
(Get-Location).ProviderPath -replace '[\\/]$' -eq $HOME
```

- **Note**: The unfortunate need for removing a trailing path separator, if present, via `-replace '[\\/]$'` stems from the fact that PowerShell, as of v7.0, *doesn't normalize* what `.ProviderPath` reports: if the current, PS-drive-based path is the *root* of that PS drive, `.ProviderPath` unexpectedly retains the trailing `\` (or `/` on Unix-like platforms) in the native path that is returned.
  This problematic behavior is the subject of [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12971).

To give a complete example:

```
# Define a custom H: drive whose root is $HOME.
$null = New-PSDrive H FileSystem $HOME

# Change to the root of the new drive, which is effectively the 
# same as $HOME, though from PowerShell's perspective the path is H:\
Set-Location H:\

# !! -> $false, because .Path reports 'H:\'
(Get-Location).Path -eq $HOME

# OK -> $true - .ProviderPath reports the true, file-system-native path.
# Note: 
#   If GitHub issue #12971 gets fixed (see above),
#   the -replace '[\\/]$' part will no longer be needed.
(Get-Location).ProviderPath -replace '[\\/]$' -eq $HOME
```

---

**Additionally**, if there's a chance that the current location is based on a *symbolic link / reparse point*, you'll have to do additional work to determine path equality.

Comment: This comment is for someone having trouble `Get-Location`. Running `New-PSDrive` and `Set-Location` inside a different scope(function, ps1, etc), then `ProviderPath` returns null. [see the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-7#description) for details. `(Get-ChildItem)[0].Parent.FullName` still works if there is at least one file... (sorry for reposting, unable to edit my own comment)

Answer (score 2):

`Get-Location` returns an object. You have to compare `$HOME` to the correct property of that object:

```
(Get-Location).Path -eq $HOME
```